# Sufficient condition to be a countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ a non empty set. Which of the following conditions is sufficient because A is a countable set:

1. $A \subset \mathbb N$
2. $\mathbb N \subset A$
3. exists a surjective function $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow A$ and $A$ is infinite
4. exists a succession $a_n$ so that $\{a_n:n \in \mathbb N\}=A$

My attemp:

1. is false because if the set $A$ is finite I can't find a bijective function fraom $\mathbb N$ to $A$
2. is false because if I take $A=\mathbb R$ is not countable

but for the other cases?

Comment: what do you mean by denumerable. Countable??

Comment: Could you check the definition.of "denumerable" in your book, and let us know whether the book considers finite sets to be 'denumerable'? Some books do, some don't.

Comment: my definition: exists $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow A$ bijective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 3 is true.

Since $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow A$ is onto hence $|A|\le |\mathbb N|$. Now given that $A$ is infinite which restricts us to the condition $|A|=|\mathbb N|$. Thus $f$ is a bijection which implies $A$ is countable.

Answer (score 3):

3. It is true. For each $a\in A$, let $n_a=\min f^{-1}(\{a\})$. Then $\Bbb N_A=\{n_a\mid a\in A\}$ is an infinite set of natural numbers and the map from $A$ to $\Bbb N_A$ defined by $f(a)=n_a$ is a bijection. Furthermore any infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ is countable.
4. It is false. If $A=\{1\}$, take $a_n=1$ form each natural $N$.